# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous Laravel whereHas returning error

Tags: eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-9, wherehas

Hello I want to filter my response by tags and categories in laravel 9. my code is :

```
$posts = Post::when($categoryId > 0, function($query) use ($categoryId) {
            return $query->where('category_id', '=', $categoryId);
        })
        ->when($tagId > 0, function($query) use ($tagId){
            return $query->whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tagId) {
                return $query->where('id', $tagId);
            });
        })
        ->get();

        return view('blog::posts.index', compact('posts', 'categories'));
```

but i got this error :
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

```
select * from `posts` where exists (select * from `tags` inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id` where `posts`.`id` = `post_tag`.`post_id` and `id` = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

change code to this

```
$posts = Post::when($categoryId > 0, function($query) use ($categoryId) {
            return $query->where('category_id', '=', $categoryId);
        })
        ->when($tagId > 0, function($query) use ($tagId){
            return $query->whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tagId) {
                return $query->where('tag.id', $tagId);
            });
        })
        ->get();

        return view('blog::posts.index', compact('posts', 'categories'));
```